# Clean a nested Select in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to clear a select, when it becomes the first select, and tried to apply
`getElementById()`, the `onClick` doesn't work for me:

```
render() {
    const { origenes, destinos } = this.state;
    const { Linea } = this.props;
    const btnLinea = 'btn-'.concat(Linea);

    return (
        <div>
            <label className="label-title">Seleccione Tramo</label>
            <Select id="origen" className="select-tramo" options={origenes}  onChange={(env) => { this.changeOrigen(env, this.state.linea); }} placeholder="Ciudad de origen"/>
            <Select id="destino" className="select-tramo" options={destinos} onChange={(env) => { this.setState({ destino: env.value }); }} placeholder="Ciudad de destino"/>
            <div className="row" style={{ marginTop: 10}}>
              <div className="col text-center">
                <Button className={btnLinea} onClick={this.aplicarFiltro} ><i className="fa fa-search"></i> Buscar</Button>
              </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
  }
```

Comment: I'm not really sure what you are trying to achieve and what the problem is. What do you mean by "I'm trying to clear a select"?

Comment: @lomse, i think what he means by "clear a select" is to de-select all options from drop down selection ...

Comment: for de select all and set it to default value. use state variable for generating the steps and then on the onClick event setState the default value